# rails4, strong params pismo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri, strong-parameters

I know how so save a page title and favicon using the pismo gem with Rails 3.2.18. My question is how can I do the same with Rails 4 strong params it's kinda confusing to me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, or if you know now of a better gem or a better way to save a page title and favicon will help 2. :)

```rb
# Rails 3.2.16
 def create
    require 'pismo'
    bookmark = Bookmark.new(params[:bookmark])
    bookmark.user_id = current_user.id

    doc = Pismo::Document.new(bookmark.link)
    @title = doc.title
    @favicon = doc.favicon
    bookmark.title = @title
    bookmark.favicon = @favicon

    flash[:error] = "your bookmark wasn't save" unless bookmark.save
    redirect_to current_user

 end
```

This is my rails 4 controller to save bookmark but I'm not really sure where or how to implement pismo gem.

```rb
# Rails 4.1.4
def create
   @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.build(bookmark_params)
   if @bookmark.save
     flash[:success] = "Bookmark save"
     redirect_to statics_home_path
   else
     redirect_to statics_home_path
  end
end
```

private

```
def bookmark_params
  params.require(:bookmark).permit(:link, :title)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
# this works with Pismo
# I'm sure it'll work with Nokogiri


def create
  require 'pismo'
  doc = Pismo::Document.new(bookmark_params[:link])
  @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.build(bookmark_params)
  @bookmark.title = doc.title.to_s

  if @bookmark.save
    #flash[:success] = "Bookmark save"
    redirect_to statics_home_path
  else
    redirect_to statics_home_path
    #render 'statics/home'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your old code worked in Rails 3.2 you should be able to just create your document as before and set `@bookmark.title` and `@bookmark.favicon` after calling `@bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.build(bookmark_params)`